# c# Add custom method to Entity generated class with visual studio

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

Can anyone tell me the specific steps to add custom methods to classes generated in from an .edmx file?

I have a ReturnedItem class, which has some simple and navigation properties.  From everything I have read, I should just be able to add a ReturnedItem.cs file to the project, and define the same class as partial, similar to the following code where I implement the fullDetails() method.

However, I get an error that "trackingNumber does not exist in the current context" for every property I use.  When I check the properties in the method with "this" it looks like ReturnedItem is a new object type that doesn't have the properties from the object defined in the model/edmx.

I'm missing something simple I'm sure, but no amount of research is pointing me towards my mistake.

```
using MyEntities;

    namespace MyEntityDataModel
    {
        public partial class ReturnedItem
        {
           public string fullDetails() {
             return "Tracking Number:" + trackingNumber;
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your actual entity class?

Comment: partial class definitions must me in the same namespace and same assembly.  you might double-check that is case.

Comment: Is this partial class in the same assembly ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course I figured it out seconds after posting.  I knew it had something to do with the namespace, which you pointed out.  It should be:

```
//using MyEntities; (don't need this)

namespace MyEntities
{
    public partial class ReturnedItem
    {
       public string fullDetails() {
         return "Tracking Number:" + trackingNumber;
       }
    }
}
```

As for the other question of posting my actual entity class, I didn't even realize how to do that.  Now I know I should be looking at the Designer.cs file (which I understand is auto-generated) but that would have easily shown me what the proper namespace was.

Thanks for the help! You are ridiculously fast!